# Xamarin bug with ClosedXML : "system.io.ioexception: operation not valid when package is read-only at system.io.packaging..."

Tags: xamarin, closedxml

I'm using Xamarin Studio to work on a C# console application. I am working with ClosedXML in order to manipulate data from an excel file.

I am getting the error

system.io.ioexception: operation not valid when package is read-only at system.io.packaging.....

When I try to read from the excel file, but the excel file is not read only.

var wb = new XLWorkbook(TestProductsXlsx);

I have tried to look on the internet but it seems that this bug has not been fixed. Can someone please help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this will end up being in a Mono 4.4 release according to the comments on https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/39